# Laravel model attributes null when i saved it but but I have validated them in the constructor

Tags: php, laravel

working with Laravel PHP, I have this model with a constructor where i set the attributes:

```
class NutritionalPlanRow extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    private $nutritional_plan_id;
    private $aliment_id;
    private $nomeAlimento;

    public function __construct($plan = null,
                                $aliment = null,
                                array $attributes = array())  {

        parent::__construct($attributes);

        if($plan){
            $this->nutritional_plan()->associate($plan);
            $this->nutritional_plan_id = $plan->id;
        }
        if($aliment){
            $this->aliment()->associate($aliment);
            $this->aliment_id = $aliment->id;
            $this->nomeAlimento = $aliment->nome;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Get the plan that owns the row.
     */
    public function nutritional_plan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\NutritionalPlan');
    }

    /**
     * Get the aliment record associated with the NutritionalPlanRow.
     */
    public function aliment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Aliment');
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * Get the value of nomeAlimento
     */
    public function getNomeAlimentoAttribute()
    {
        return $this->nomeAlimento;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of plan_id
     */
    public function getNutritional_Plan_IdAttribute()
    {
        return $this->nutritional_plan_id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of aliment_id
     */
    public function getAliment_IdAttribute()
    {
        return $this->aliment_id;
    }
}
```

Then I have a controller where I initialize the object:

```
public function addAlimentToPlan(Request $request){

        $planId = $request->planId;
        $alimentId = $request->alimentId;

        $validatedData = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'planId' => ['required'],
        'alimentId' => ['required'],
    ]);

    if ($validatedData->fails()) {
        return back()->withErrors($validatedData, 'aliment');
    }

    $plan = NutritionalPlan::find($planId);
    $aliment = Aliment::find($alimentId);

    $nutritionalPlanRow = new NutritionalPlanRow($plan, $aliment);

    Log::info('Nome Alimento '.$nutritionalPlanRow->getNomeAlimentoAttribute());

    $nutritionalPlanRow->save(); //

    Toastr::success( 'Alimento aggiunto', '',
        ["positionClass" => "toast-bottom-right",
        "closeButton" => "true"]);

    return back();
}
```

The save operation return this error:
**SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERRORE: null value in column "nomeAlimento" of relation "nutritional_plan_rows"**

but logging the $nutritionalPlanRow->getNomeAlimentoAttribute() the attribure is enhanced.

Someone can help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor you have the following line:

```php
$this->nomeAlimento = $aliment->nome;
```

You believe that this will fill the attribute in the eloquent model, but that is not happening. Normally such an assignment will pass the magic `__set` method on the model, but not during model/object construction.

You actually assign it to a property on the object, which is later accessible by your log function, but eloquent doesn't know about it. Therefore it is not sent to the database, resulting in a null error (no default value).

You may use the following to set the values in the constructor:

```php
$this->setAttribute('nomeAlimento', $aliment->nome);
```

This calls the setAttribute function on the eloquent model, the attribute this becomes part of the model.

(Make sure to change also the other line in your constructor where you assign a value to the object)